# QR-Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation

I should make a program in which with help of QR-decomposition find approximation of `x^sinx` shaped `a+bLnx+c*e^x` for a values x € {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.
I do not have idea how to start.If somebody knows more about this method please help me,than I will continue.

Comment: You might post correct code for the problem, even if you don't know how to program the solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is very easily done with `LinearModelFit`

```
data = Table[{x, x^Sin[x]}, {x, 1, 7}];

Normal[LinearModelFit[data, {Log[x], Exp[x]}, x]]
(* 1.66952 + 0.00332217 E^x - 1.01323 Log[x] *)
```